# Почему не преобразуется значение value в контент вектора?

Tags: html, css, icon, вектор

Не могу, понять, почему на **стоке** срабатывает значение `value="&#xf002;"` у `input`, а на [фидле](https://jsfiddle.net/nspmaok9/2/) нет и на сайте у меня тоже..

```css
.searchSubmit {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<input type="submit" class="searchSubmit" value="&#xf002;">
```

Comment: В одном браузере проверяете? У меня и там, и там преобразовалось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что надо смотреть ошибки в консоли разработчика.

В частности на jsfiddle

> (index):31 Mixed Content: The page at `'https://jsfiddle.net/nspmaok9/2/'` was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet `'http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'`. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Для быстрого решения, можно *всегда* загружать стили по https

```
https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css
```

https://jsfiddle.net/avvguu7w/

Comment: Меня волшебный кэш спас от ошибки, не в том направлении думать стал...

Comment: @Grundy а, если я на сайте подключаю через `wp_enqueue_style` - тогда как быть?

Comment: @Вася, даже не знаю, что это такое. Но наверняка можно настроить что и откуда брать

Comment: @Grundy, все разобрался - у меня был указана цифра 3им параметром в `wp_enqueue_style` и похоже загружалась раньше, чем это было положено